# Why does curl localhost provide expected output but navigating to ec2 public IP does not using nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have been stuck trying to get nginx started up on my ec2 instance. All I have done is install nginx and seems to be running as expected within the server.

Running `curl localhost` serves the default nginx file as expected. Navigating to the public IP, I just get a **site can't be reached error (IP refused to connect)**.

From my understanding, the inbound rules have also been setup correctly. I have not changed any of the configuration files from nginx as I just want to test that it is working. Everything is left as default. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is occurring? Thank you so much. [image]

[image: Inbound]

```
netstat -ntlp
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the `netstat -ntlp` output.  The trouble seems to me that, your nginx is listening on `localhost` which is a loopback address and cant be reached from outside.

Comment: @samtoddler I've attached the output for `netstate -ntlp`. I haven't made any changes to default so I am a little confused to why it would be set up that way.

Comment: can you do curl on the machine's ip like `curl 172.xx.xx.xx`. Check if there are iptables rules or nginx error logs are there. I did installed fresh nginx on an ec2 instance `ubuntu` worked for me.

Comment: Yes  I can curl on the instance IP and it works as expected. As I haven't made any changes I can try spinning up another instance. Could issue this be global to my AWS account or just for this instance?

Comment: I would still suggest to check the networking on your VPC, like if route tables are in place or are there are any Network ACLs being applied, any aws network firewall configured. Are there any other instance, which you can access this way ?

Comment: @samtoddler Out of curiosity, I navigated the public IP using my phone and it works. Is there a reason as to why my pc is not able to access it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229051/discussion-between-safder-and-samtoddler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by my firewall rules blocking access to the public IP address. If this issue occurs to anyone else, check if the IP is working on another device connected to the same network. I then flushed my iptables and restarted my pc and it started working.